# SMA Runbook doesn't get executed

Tags: azure, spf, wap

I'm trying to build POC Azure Pack environment and got stuck with SMA.

I've deployed both web services and runbook worker on one server. Another server has SPF and WAP installed. Please see configuration below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Ive configured runbook SPF to be executed on VM update

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately this configuration doesn't work. When I reset, power on/off tenant VMs using tenant portals runbooks dosn't get executed. IIS logs on SMA servers doesn't show any request to run this runbook, but if I run this runbook manually it will complete successfully and I will see some info in IIS logs.

Any ideas why runbook doesn't get executed?

Comment: those hooks were always a pain in the bottom. are you sure that's the correct hook, i would assume that there is a hook for start\stop vm. and this one is probably when you change vm configuration

Comment: I've also used hooks for create vm, delete vm, create network, delete network. None of the worked. I'd be glad to try your way but can you give me the name of the hook you see fit?

Comment: well, that means you've misconfigured something, i doubt there are a lot of folks on this planet who can troubleshoot this issue via a forum thread (i'm certainly not one of them), man, I've had setups where this error would haunt me. can you ping me on skype? I can try to help you

Comment: I think I can. How can I find you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was with the certificates, figured that out after a skype session

Comment: Server name, stated in azure must be equal to the one that is stated within certificate.